# txpostgres stop reactor when db goes offline

Tags: python, twisted, postgresql-9.1

Looking at this example:
http://txpostgres.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#automatic-reconnection

I was wondering how to stop the reactor completely (instead of reestablishing the db connection) in case the db is stopped or restarted.

Answer (score 0):

The reactor is stopped using [`reactor.stop()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#stop).

Comment: Yes, but where do I have to put it?

Comment: Read the documentation for the class the example uses, <http://txpostgres.readthedocs.org/en/latest/txpostgres.html#txpostgres.reconnection.DeadConnectionDetector>.  It explains what callback methods are available and under what circumstances they are called.  For example, notice that for `connectionRecovered` it says "Called when the connection has recovered."  So if you wanted some code to run after a connection is "recovered" (after it has been re-established) you would override this method and put the code there.